# Using LINQ in a List

Tags: c#, linq

I want to use LINQ to find a group of data objects in a List. I am currently iterating on the collections to find what I need.

I have searched and read lots of examples online but I cannot make sense enough of it to do what I need.

The data object I want to search is called a "Property" in my code.
A Property has a Generic List of "Attribute". An Attribute has a Generic List of string that has two items, a name and a value.

Data in List:

```
 Property_Data
 {
    Attribute {name="Color" value=""}
    Attribute {name="Size" value=""}
    Attribute {name="Width" value=""}
    Attribute {name="Display" value=""}
 }
```

Example of the property with populated attributes

```
My_Property
    Color = black
    Size = 12
    Width = 2
    Display = True
```

Here is the code I use where I iterate each Property object then I iterate each item in the collection of Attributes searching for the attribute with the name of "Display" and the value of "True".

```
  foreach (IPropertyData prop_data in Properties)
  {
    if (prop_data.Attributes.Find(a => a.Name == "Display").Value == "True")
    {
       // do something here
    }                                    
  }
```

What I want to learn is how to search the collection of Property data objects thing using LINQ so I don't have to iterate each Property and then the attributes of the property.

Here is my attempt at it:

```
  IEnumerable<IPropertyData> prop_datas = Properties
       .Where(p => p.Attributes.Where(a => a.Name == "isDisplayable" &&  a.Value == "True");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if(prop_data.Attributes.Any(cc=>cc.Name == "Display" && cc.Value == "True"))
{
  // Do your work
}
```

If you consider complete collection then

```
Properties.ForEach(item=> {
       if(item.Attributes.Any(cc=>cc.Name == "Display" && cc.Value == "True"))
       {
          // Do your work.
       }  
});
```

After your question update

```
IEnumerable<IPropertyData> prop_datas = Properties
       .Where(p => p.Attributes.Any(cc=>cc.Name == "Display" && cc.Value == "True"));
```

Comment: What I was after was a way to search on the Properties collection and not each individual Property data object.  I have updated my question to include my attempt at LINQ. Notice that I am searching on the "Properties" object and not iterating over each Property.

Comment: Jon Skeet has a heap of blog posts called edulinq which is great for really seeing how LINQ works. http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/category/edulinq/ . It's worth learning all these methods so that they are second nature.

Answer (score 0):

```
var query = 
    from prop_data in Properties
    where prop_data.Attribute("IsDisplayable") == "True"
    select prop_data;
```

the query variable should now contain everything in the list where its IsDisplable attribute is "True". If you wanted to go over each element you have found you can simply do something like

```
foreach (var item in query)
{
 // item.Attribute("IsDisplayable") = False;
}
```